# If Thor is the god of thunder, why does he control lightning, even indoors?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

Okay, I can kind of deal with him being the god of thunder and controlling lightning since thunder is a product of the former. The thing I have a real problem with is when he controls lightning indoors (happens often in comic books and I think in the MCU as well). The reason why is because [lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) is an electrostatic discharge between a cloud and a cloud, or a cloud and the earth. So by definition, lightning cannot happen indoors. What Thor is really doing is just controlling electricity. Does anyone care to explain this away? I mean I have no problem with him having that ability, I have just never seen that stated it in any description of any version of Thor.

Comment: Maybe because "god of thunder, lightning, and electrical discharges reminiscent of lightning and emanating from sources other than clouds" doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that they need to change his subtitle, just wondering if anyone has seen a description of his powers where they account for this. They had a really nice one explaining his flight, but that was all. Can't recall which series it was though.

Comment: Probably somebody can find an explanation. I was mostly just joking. Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: Pretty sure you're just looking WAAAY too deep into this.

Comment: I figured it was a joke lol. I have been looking for a while, which is what drove me to join the community. Thanks!

Comment: @AerisFang The OP is on the right site then. We spend all day looking way too deep into things like this.

Comment: @AerisFang I am, but it is Marvel's fault for doing a full page just explaining his flight, now I want more!!!

Comment: Thor controls the thunderclouds, makes them really, really small and brings them with him 7/24. *Word.*

Comment: @MajorStackings that is great! I was playing around with an idea that he forms his own clouds, but yours is less outrageous since we wouldn't see them anyway... kudos

Comment: @MajorStackings Is that the metric way to say 24/7?

Comment: I almost wrote 31... ;)

Comment: So 3.429, or 0.29167?

Comment: If someone were the god of smoke, would you wonder why they also control fire? Should the god of rain not also have the ability to create and control rainstorms, including the requisite clouds, humidity, dew point, winds, etc.? Would not the god of wine also have at least some influence on grapes? Surely we would want the god of plumbers to have the power to make pants fit poorly, the god of European metal music to have the power of bad English grammar, and the god of internet trolls to have the power to post anonymously, even on moderated forums.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yes, if there were a *pyrogaseous* god I would wonder a lot of things about them (;

Comment: Perhaps, if the people from the middle ages knew what electricity is, they called Thor the “god of thunder and electricity”. But the knew lightnings.

Comment: Lightning is an electrostatic discharge, period.  In nature, it happens to build up between clouds and earth.  Even if that were the accepted exclusive scientific definition, ancient Vikings did not understand the physical science behind it (hence, attributing it to gods), so that definition along with any indoor/outdoor restrictions would not apply to the god.

Thor is able to control electrical discharges, not "lightning," per se.  It's a convenient label for his abilities, nothing more.

Comment: [Indoor Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator)

Comment: It should be noted (as I think @Holger was getting at), the "god of thunder" bit was *not* a Marvel invention.  It is a (rough) translation of the original descriptions of the Norse god Thor, on which Marvel's Thor was based.  At the time the vikings were worshipping the Norse gods, there really was no concept of "electricity", nor of the modern formal definition of "lightning", so assuming there was a god who could manipulate electrical discharges in general, that would most likely be perceived/described by the vikings simply as a "god of lighting/thunder" anyway.

Comment: And if he's the God of Hammers, why doesn't he ever get nailed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Maybe because "god of thunder, lightning, and electrical discharges reminiscent of lightning and emanating from sources other than clouds" doesn't have the same ring to it. Seriously. With all credit to @armadillo.

#### Legendary Thor

Given the source material for most mythological entities through history started primarily as word of mouth storytelling, you would suspect his appellation, Thor, God of Thunder to be all one need say to get the point across.

[image: Legendary Thor, red haired, red beard, gauntlets and belt of strength]

*Legendary Thor, red haired, red beard, gauntlets and belt of strength*

> - The 11th century Christian missionary Adam of Bremen, on noting the great temple of the gods in Uppsala, Sweden, wrote, "Thor, they say, presides over the air, he governs the thunder and lightening, the winds and rains, fair weather and crops...If plague and famine threaten, a libation is poured to the idol Thor." **[-- Mythical Realm: Thor](http://mythicalrealm.com/legends/thor.html)**

Unlike fans and adherents of religion today with far greater knowledge of science and rational thinking, primitive man wouldn't have dared to question how Thor threw his lightning. They speculated about it but kept their opinions to themselves. Bolder storytellers said this:

> - During a thunderstorm, Thor rode through the heavens on his chariot pulled by the goats Tanngrisni ("gap-tooth") and Tanngnost ("tooth grinder"). Lightning flashed whenever he threw his hammer Mjollnir. Mjollnir ("that smashes") was made for him by the dwarfs Brok and Eitri, who made many magical objects for the gods.

They dared to describe his legendary strength, fearsome enemies and final fate as:

> - Thor wears the belt Megingjard which doubles his already considerable strength. His greatest enemy is Jormungand, the Midgard Serpent. At the day of Ragnarok, Thor will kill this serpent but will die from its poison. His sons will inherit his hammer after his death. Ragnarok ("Doom of the Gods"), also called Gotterdammerung, means the end of the cosmos in Norse mythology.

His legendary hammer was said to be able to kill a giant dead in a single blow, split a mountain range in half and return to his hand as quickly as a bolt of lighting. As legends go, this seems pretty complete and everything else is probably a local legend or tale which was later found and compiled by later generations. Legendary Thor was a bad-ass and was more popular than his father Odin.

#### Marvel's Thor

[image]

As for Thor, the Marvelous re-creation of Jack Kirby and Stan Lee, his powers were not required to resemble the original mythological being and since they were creating a comic which needed visual pizzazz, they took liberties:

- Thor would retain his ability to summon and command storms, wind, rain and lightning, with Mjolnir or without it. Those powers are within him. Mjolnir amplifies them.
- Mjolnir would have all of the powers of myth and dozens more including the ability to absorb energy, move through time (rescinded) distort electromagnetic fields, generate electrical discharges and project powerful bursts of god-force energy capable of destroying almost anything.
- He would have the strength of his father and his mother and be stronger than all of the other gods in Asgard, twice as strong with his magical belt and gloves
- He would fly without the use of his previous chariot and goat steeds mentioned above. He would whirl his hammer above his head, and throw it, hanging on to its invulnerable strap.

Why can he do all of this? Because in a universe with Iron Man, Giant-Man, the Hulk, Ulik the Troll, the Wrecking Crew and the Absorbing Man, all who possess powers similar to the gods of legend, Thor would still need to be seen as god-like in their eyes.

Thus Kirby and Lee ensured, no matter who came into existence after Thor, his power levels ensured he would be acknowledged and respected as a powerful force for good in the Marvel Universe.

This meant sometimes shooting lighting from Mjolnir because he could and the All-Father gave him a weapon that could do that. Superpowers don't subscribe to historical or legendary limitations. While superheroes are mythical in nature, their creators are quite happy to take liberties with the legends as they see fit.

**The long and the short of it is:** Marvel writers wanted him to be able to control electricity along with lightning. It's that simple.

Comment: Good answer. I think your first line pretty much answers the question by itself, but the comparison is welcome nonetheless. Primitive people wouldn't have seen electricity other than lightning, so it's reasonable to think his abilities could just be extended to all electricity.

Answer (score -1):

If he's the GOD of thunder (and lightning) he, obviously, can make them appear and happen anywhere he wants, he's not tied to physical or natural rules because he's a GOD.

You say that lightning is electricity discharging from a cloud to the ground. That's fair in our world. In a world with a god of thunder and lightning, lightning are an extension of it's pure will... sure, they usually happen from cloud to ground, but it's master just can summon them whenever he wants in the way he wants.

A good advice: stop trying to explain fantasy through science. It's a good idea to do it on science fiction, as science fiction try to keep in touch with reality and science, but this is not true with fantasy.